# where set Access-Control-Allow-Origin to localhosto:4200

Tags: php, angular, laravel

i´m using laravel 10 and angular 15

my cors.php looks like

```
 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:4200'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => ["Set-Cookie"],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

but chrome i get the request
like this

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Connection: Upgrade, Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Sat, 10 Jun 2023 02:28:17 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Server: Apache/2.4.55 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1s PHP/8.2.5

Set-Cookie:laravel_session=eyJpdiI6ImpBdGxBZWtwZ2pGa1NQL1FjbFR6QVE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiWm5VMDZBTGpWanhQbVJkTnJsbVZrbTE0WmFOU1c4dFNVNVNBSzgxUkd2WDliR3N6ZzJzT3A2UDVVdlRwdHFoSU14c080cFloMXc4RWZSMFpUYy8rN1RrOStZb1pvd3o2SHJkcWdMeGc5TGRDTXVYc0FLZUJPVkJiM2xOSU1jUHgiLCJtYWMiOiJlYzBlNTI1NDJhNGNmZWUxY2M4OTJhMWE1NzY4NDNmZGM5ZmU3YTNjMjc1MTM0ODg0M2MwMDFkMzBmOTY5MjdmIiwidGFnIjoiIn0%3D; expires=Sat, 10 Jun 2023 04:28:18 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/; httponly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Upgrade: h2,h2c
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.2.5
```

];

i dont know where is setted

my angular request is

```
this.http.get('http://localhost/' + route, {withCredentials:true} )
        .subscribe({
          next: (res) => { console.log("Next: ", message, "--> " + JSON.stringify (res)  + " <--") },
          error: (res) => { console.log("Error", message, res) }
        });
```

i need to recieve the response header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'https://localhost:4200'
```

this is wrong to browser

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:'*'
```

Comment: There might be some funkiness because you are trying to set the value to localhost, test by changing it to a random domain to see if it sets. Also test by removing the `http://`. Also, what is the value of `route`. And finally: https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors/issues/459#issuecomment-652987685 running those commands may help.